# Selenium Chrome on Raspberry Pi 3B+ shows only "data:,"

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, raspberry-pi, chromium

I am trying to use my raspberry pi to web scrape with Selenium, but when I try to get a website, the address bar of Chromium only shows "data:,".

```
ser = Service('usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = ser)
driver.get("bbc.co.uk")
```

chromium-chromedriver version is 98.0.4758.106-rpt1

chromium version is 98.0.4758.106 on Raspbian 11 (32-bit)

Comment: You may just need to add "https://" to the beginning of the URL.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately that doesn’t work, is there anything else I can try?

Comment: I got redirected to "https://www.bbc.com/" so maybe try with that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the same version. I think that this is coming from chromium or chromedriver version. I was using Raspbian Bullseye.

I change the OS for Raspbian Buster and now it is working fine.

Chromium version : 90.0.4430.212